# C#: Get XML node content with all parent tags

Tags: c#, xml, linq

There is a XML file:

```
<favorites>
    <movies>
        <movie title="The Godfather" year="1974" />
        <movie title="The Terminator" year="1984" />
        <movie title="Dark Knight" year="2008" />
    </movies>

    <books>
        <book title = "1984" author="George Orwell" />
        <book title = "Robinson Crusoe"" author="Daniel Defoe"/>
        <book title = "Frankenstein" author="Mary Shelly" />
    </books>

    <music>
        <artist title = "Beatles" genre="rock" />
        <artist title = "Queen" genre="rock" />
        <artist title = "Metallica" rock="heavy metal" />
    </music>
</favorites>
```

I need to filter a specific node (music) *with all parent & child* nodes.
The result should be:

```
<favorites>
  <music>
    <artist title="Beatles" genre="rock" />
    <artist title="Queen" genre="rock" />
    <artist title="Metallica" rock="heavy metal" />
  </music>
</favorites>
```

I've found a solution to filter XML using System.XML & LINQ:

```
 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);    
 xdoc.Descendants()
     .Where(x => x.Name != "favorites" & x.Name != "music" & x.Name != "artist")
     .Remove();    
 Console.WriteLine(xdoc.ToString());
```

The working sample is here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NnA4h7#

The problem is that I have to specify all parent & child nodes in my query.

Is there a way to get the same result with specifying a wanted node only (movies, books, music) ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method that is a little simpler :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement favorites = doc.Descendants("favorites").FirstOrDefault();

            favorites.ReplaceNodes(favorites.Element("music")));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Ok for this example, but won't work if wil be another nodes between <favorites> and <music> , for example favorites -> myfavorites -> music, in this case we still need to specify all parent nodes to get result... But good point is that we don't need to specify child nodes.

Comment: It will work.  You do not understand the code.  favorites.Element("music") will find any child element of favorites and only the one child.

Comment: Please look at sample https://dotnetfiddle.net/vAmP8z , there is a result with additional intermediate nodes - it gives only the <favorites> and no more...

Comment: I updated code to use ReplaceNodes instead of ReplaceWith.  Your example does not match users XML.  My code will work with your example if  I use favorites.Descendants("music") (change element to descendant).

Comment: Now it works, thanks. I'll try to figure out which option is more usable a little later.

Comment: @jdweng, I like the approach but it probably needs some changes to handle more complex xml. Following your comments you propose to use `favorites.ReplaceNodes(favorites.Descendants("music"));`.  However if your xml has an additional level, let's say structure looks like `favorites/level1/movies`, resulting xml is still `favorites/movies` which is incorrect in this case.

Comment: That is why every computer program is different!!!!  If your data and inputs are always the same then you would need only one computer program and you can fire all the software programmers because you wouldn't need them any more.  When you change your input requirements your program changes.  When the shoe fits wear it.  When the shoe doesn't fit get a different one.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to remove all nodes except for the parents of music, music itself and its descendants.

```
var music = xdoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "music");
xdoc.Descendants().Where(x =>
    !music.AncestorsAndSelf().Contains(x)
    && !music.Descendants().Contains(x)
).Remove();
Console.WriteLine(xdoc.ToString());
```

It returns:

```
<favorites>
  <music>
    <artist title="Beatles" genre="rock" />
    <artist title="Queen" genre="rock" />
    <artist title="Metallica" rock="heavy metal" />
  </music>
</favorites>
```

**UPDATE**: supporting multiple nested levels between favorites and music. Optimized for running with big files:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var music = xdoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "music");
var parents = music.Ancestors().Reverse()
    .Select(a=>new XElement(a.Name.LocalName)).ToArray();
XElement root = new XElement(xdoc.Root.Name.LocalName);
XDocument xdoc2 = new XDocument(root);
XElement lastAdded = root;
for (int i = 1; i < parents.Count(); i++)
{
    lastAdded.Add(parents[i]);
    lastAdded = parents[i];
}
lastAdded.Add(music);
Console.WriteLine(xdoc2.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks gracefully and works fine with small xml data, but there is some performance issue with a big one... I have xml file with a few thousand elements, and this removing query takes over 10 minutes and still has no result :(

Comment: My original answer was based on your code that remove elements. If you work with big data we need to use different approach. Since a node knows its ancestors one thing we can do is creating new xml that reproduces the path till music node. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Works perfectly! I believe this is one of the best solutions for this task.