# Removing element from list property in class

Tags: c#, xml, linq

There is a XML data serialized in C# System.Xml.Serialization.

There is a root class describing root element . It contains fileds of List type described in descendant classes (like Movie).

I can deserialize my XML document into a class, and add a new element in list simply using List.Add or List.Insert:

```
cfg.Movies.Insert(0, new Movie("Newly added: Pulp Fiction", "1994"));
```

But reverse operation doesn't work:

```
cfg.Movies.Remove(new Movie("To be removed: The Godfather", "1974"));
```

So the question is how can I remove an element from xml class list?

The sample is here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WqCNoD

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{

    string xmlString =
        @"<favorites>
                <movies>
                    <movie title=""To be removed: The Godfather"" year=""1974"" />
                    <movie title=""The Terminator"" year=""1984"" />
                    <movie title=""Dark Knight"" year=""2008"" />
                </movies>

                <books>
                    <book title = ""1984"" author=""George Orwell"" />
                    <book title = ""Robinson Crusoe"" author=""Daniel Defoe "" />
                    <book title = ""Frankenstein"" author=""Mary Shelly"" />
                </books>

                <music>
                    <artist title = ""Beatles"" genre=""rock"" />
                    <artist title = ""Queen"" genre=""rock"" />
                    <artist title = ""Metallica"" rock=""heavy metal"" />
                </music>
            </favorites>";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

    var xdocData = xdoc.ToString();

    //DeSerialization
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Favorites));
    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xdoc.ToString()))
    {
        Favorites cfg = (Favorites) serializer.Deserialize(reader);


        // Add & remove element
        cfg.Movies.Insert(0, new Movie("Newly added: Pulp Fiction", "1994"));
        cfg.Movies.Remove(new Movie("To be removed: The Godfather", "1974"));


        //Serialization
        XmlSerializer serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(cfg.GetType());

        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer2.Serialize(writer, cfg);
            Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());

        }

    }
}



[XmlRoot(ElementName = "favorites", DataType = "string", IsNullable = true)]
public class Favorites
{
    //public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("movies")]
    [XmlArrayItem("movie")]
    public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    public Favorites()
    {
        Movies = new List<Movie>();
    }
}


public class Movie
{
    [XmlAttribute("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("year")]
    public string Year { get; set; }

    public Movie() { }

    public Movie(string title, string year)
    {
        Title = title;
        Year = year;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you create a new object its reference is not in the list yet. You need to search the list for the item you wish to remove then remove it using the result of the search. Something like: `var toRemove = cfg.Movies.Single(m => m.Title == "To be removed: The Godfather" && m.Year == "1974"); cfg.Movies.Remove(toRemove)`;

Comment: It's not an "xml class". It's just a regular class that happens to have serialization attributes on it.

Comment: What is difference between this request and the one yesterday? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867071/c-get-xml-node-content-with-all-parent-tags/49867789#comment86767137_49867789

Comment: @jdweng, it's completely different questions, they have only the similar xml data. First one relates to filtering xml nodes at all, and this one relates specifically to operation with XmlArray and List. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new object its reference is not in the list yet. You need to search the list for the item you wish to remove then remove it using the result of the search.

Something like:

```
var movieToRemove = cfg.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Title == "To be removed: The Godfather" && m.Year == "1974");
if (moveiToRemove != null)
  cfg.Movies.Remove(movieToRemove);
```

Comment: Could you please explain whats going on here - cfg.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Title == "To be removed: The Godfather" && m.Year == "1974") ? Can it be described in other way?

Comment: It's a Linq query that selects exactly one item in the list. If there isn't an item or there are multiple items that match the criteria the default value (often null) is returned. The criteria is that the `Title` and `Year` must match for each object `m`.

Comment: I get exception if there's no matching element in list.. Is there a way to handle this without try-catch?

Comment: You shouldn't get any exception. You should get `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to remove a new movie rather than the one that you deserialized.

You have to find the movie in your list first, then remove it.

Replace

```
cfg.Movies.Remove(new Movie("To be removed: The Godfather", "1974"));
```

With

```
cfg.Movies.Remove(cfg.Movies.Find(x => x.Title == "Newly added: Pulp Fiction"));
```

Comment: Have a knowledge lack here :( cfg.Movies.Find(x => x.Title == "Newly added: Pulp Fiction") - how it works? Is there a way to code the same without "=>" ?

Comment: the "x =>  x.Title == "Newly added: Pulp Fiction" is a predicate instruction, it basically says: get me the "x" occurence in my Movies list where x.Title is equal to "Newly added: Pulp Fiction". This is implemented by LINQ feautre of C#. Here's a turorial in order for you to understand the basics of it tutorialspoint.com/linq/linq_overview.htm Also why don't you want to use this syntax ?

Comment: Thanks. I prefer to use things that I understand good, and LINQ for now is not fully clear topic to me. So I just wanted to know - is it like a syntax sugar, or it has no alternative in this case?

Comment: You could start by looping to your list of movies and if one of them has for title the value seeked, then store in a variable. Afteward proceed to remove from the list the variable containing the occurrence